# Why does my express code cause the firebase emulator to fail?

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

This is using express.js and firebase.

If I try and access a different file with routes on it, it fails.

This code fails, and gives me this error instead of emulating successfully.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.set("views", "./pug-views");

const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes.js");

//app.use("/user", userRoutes);

app.get("/lol", (req, res) => {
     res.status(200).send({ data: "It works hopefully" });
});

exports.app = functions
    .region("europe-west1")
    .https.onRequest(app);
```

> functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error

But this code works completely fine.

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.set("views", "./pug-views");

//const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes.js");

//app.use("/user", userRoutes);

app.get("/lol", (req, res) => {
     res.status(200).send({ data: "It works hopefully" });
});

exports.app = functions
    .region("europe-west1")
    .https.onRequest(app);
```

Can someone please explain why firebase breaks if I try and access another file? I have checked the route itself and it is valid.

Commenting out all the code in `userRoutes.js` doesn't make a difference. This is the file I am trying to access (`userRoutes.js`):

```js
// Firebase imports
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { firebaseConfig } = require("../firebase.js");

// Express imports
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


console.log(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = getAuth(app);


router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).end();
});



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to share the structure of your project so that we can see where everything is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the import statements in `userRoutes.js` into require() statements.

This is my code:
`index.js`

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");

const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes.js");
const app = express();

app.set("views", "./pug-views");


app.use("/user", userRoutes);

app.get("/lol", (req, res) => {
     res.status(200).send({ data: "It works hopefully" });
});

exports.app = functions
    .region("europe-west1")
    .https.onRequest(app);
```

`userRoutes.js`:

```js
// Firebase imports
const { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } = require("firebase/auth");
const { initializeApp } = require("firebase/app");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { firebaseConfig } = require("../firebase.js");

// Express imports
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();


console.log(firebaseConfig);

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = getAuth(app);


router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).end();
});

module.exports = router;
```